# Prepending template to img inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I need to dynamically put template above static img, which is located in div. To be more precised after I run function template(){} twice I want my HTML code to be like this one:

```
   <div class="main">
           <div id="templateID"></div>
           <div id="templateID"></div>
           <img src="~/Content/img/preload.gif" id="gifLoad"/>
    </div>
```

Before run my HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="main">
    <img src="~/Content/img/preload.gif" id="gifLoad"/>
</div>
```

After running function template(){} twice my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <img src="~/Content/img/preload.gif" id="gifLoad"/> 
  <div id="templateID"></div>
  <div id="templateID"></div>
</div>
```

The function which suppose to add a template above img looks like this.

```
function template(data) {
        var parent = $('.main');

        var template = '<div id="templateID"></div>';

        var parent2 = $('#gifLoad');
        $('template').prependTo(parent2);

        parent.append(template);

    })

}
```

Can You help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is:

- `.append()` appends the data, to the end of the element.
- `.prepend()` prepends the data, to the start of the element.

Use `.prepend()` instead of `.append()`:

```
parent.prepend(template);
```

And also, it is not a good idea to duplicate `id`s, as they are meant to be unique. It is better to change the `ElementID` before prepending the data.

Comment: Which comment of mine?

Comment: I remember having it with a smiley `:P`. I guess it should have been flagged for being too chatty! Sorry about that.

Comment: @Alexander Holy cow lads, I really thank You for Your time. I pass vote to Praveen because he was 1 min earlier and both Your answers are similar. You are two professional developers arguing for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.append`

```
var parent = $('.main');
var template = '<div class="templateID"></div>';
parent.prepend(template.clone());
parent.prepend(template);
```

OR use `.before()`

```
var template = '<div class="templateID"></div>';
$("#gifLoad").before(template);
$("#gifLoad").before(template.clone());
```

*Should not use duplicate ids. Use class instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of [`$.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), also `id` ***must*** be unique (`<div id="templateID"></div>`), change it to class

```js
function template(data) {
    var parent = $('.main');
    var template = '<div class="templateID"></div>';
    
    parent.prepend(template);
}

template();
template();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <img src="~/Content/img/preload.gif" id="gifLoad"/>
</div>
```